# How do I create a footer in Sencha that will be docked unless the content overflows the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sencha-touch

I'm creating a native app using Phonegap and Sencha (not my choice). I have some pages with very little content that I want my footer to be on the bottom of. So, I simply dock the footer bottom. However, on other pages where the content overflows the viewport I do not want the footer to be awkwardly docked over the top of that content that has now run past it. In that case, where the content overflows the viewport, I want the footer to be in the flow of the page, to be scrolable with the page. Fixing that is easy by simply moving the footer into the page flow. So, in theory I could simply configure the footer to be either docked or in the page flow for every page. But, thats unreasonable and unrealistic for pages in the app that dynamically produce content from the DB creating pages with one item and others with hundreds.

So, how can I create some functionality that looks at the page, assesing the content on the page in comparison to the viewport and then automatically sets the footer to be either docked bottom on tiny pages, or in the page flow on longer pages?

[Functionality Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5GWG.png)

Comment: Can you provide some HTML/CSS so we can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so some of this depends on what components you are using and the layout affecting them.. but after a few mins of messing around I came up with this.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config: {

        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Titebar'
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',

            // represents a page
            // the height of this container is set to 100%
            //
            height: '100%',
            scrollable: true,
            items: [{
                // extra long content
                // html: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",

                // shorter content
                html: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",

                // min height of container is 100% of viewport height (vh)
                // then subtract the height of the footer.
                //
                style: 'min-height: calc(100vh - 95px);'

            }, {

                // if toolbar is the same across multiple pages
                // you can create a new class of this toolbar and
                // reference it by xtype: 'myreusablefooter'
                //
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: 'footer items...'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

You can play with it here.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/14uo/preview

And you can see the code here

https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=14uo#fiddle/14uo